# Trouble in executing second query | making relationships in ACCESS via C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

What is wrong in this code?

I got refresh access problem when 2nd query is execute

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.15.0; data source=" + user + ".accdb");
con.Open();
OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand("alter table Mail add constraint fk_id foreign key(CID) references Bio(CID)", con);
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

OleDbConnection con2 = new OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.15.0; data source=" + user + ".accdb");
con2.Open();
OleDbCommand comm2 = new OleDbCommand("alter table Num add constraint fk_id foreign key(CID) references Bio(CID)", con2);
comm2.ExecuteNonQuery();
con2.Close();
```

Comment: Please provide the exact error message if any.

Comment: error is same like, when u try to 2nd execute querry without refreshing database or closing the previous connection,  IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).

Comment: Why do you create two connections? Unless you've got a good reason, you should probably open one connection, wrap it in a using, and run both commands

Comment: i tried same error appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try running your code the second statement produces the error

> There is already a relationship named 'fk_id' in the current database.

Change the second statement so it uses a different name for the foreign key constraint (or "relationship", as Access calls them).